# Why some properties does not work with a:visited?

Tags: html, css

In my browser, Chrome on Mac OS, text-decoration and background color does not work for the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/5CYHZ/10/

Why would that be so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector) removed the ability to style most aspects of `:visited` links for privacy reasons. I would assume the same is true of Chrome and others.

Comment: Not entirely correct - Mozilla removed the ability for **JavaScript** to pull the computed styles of visited links (`getComputedStyles` will always pull the *unvisited* styles) and *limited* (not removed) the styles that could be applied to visited links.

Comment: Right, adjusted my answer to say they removed styling of 'most aspects' of :visited links.

Comment: I understand limiting `getComputedStyles`, but why would they limit CSS styles themselves?

Comment: If styles affecting layout were allowed, then JS could infer the results by looking at the size of containing elements. I don't know why background-*color* would matter though.